# I have to keep refreshing the page so my data pops up

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I'm running into a problem where I enter data into a form and then when I submit it, it accepts the data, but I have to refresh the page for the data to show up,

```
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {AddWorkouts} from "../../services/api";

export class AddWorkout extends Component {
    state = {
        name: "",
        weight: 0,
        reps: 0,
        sets: 0,
    };

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log(this.props.ws);

        AddWorkouts(this.state, this.props.ws.id).then((res) =>
            this.props.dispatch({type: "ADD_WORKOUT", payload: res})
        );
    };

    handleNameChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({name: event.target.value});
    };

    handleWeightChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({weight: event.target.value});
    };

    handleRepsChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({reps: event.target.value});
    };

    handleSetChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({sets: event.target.value});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="workout-form">
                <h1>Add your workouts</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>Name: </label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        onChange={this.handleNameChange}
                        value={this.state.name}
                    />
                    <label> Weight: </label>
                    <input
                        type="number"
                        onChange={this.handleWeightChange}
                        value={this.state.weight}
                        step="5"
                        min="0"
                    />
                    <label> Reps: </label>
                    <input
                        type="number"
                        onChange={this.handleRepsChange}
                        value={this.state.reps}
                        min="0"
                    />
                    <label> Sets: </label>
                    <input
                        type="number"
                        onChange={this.handleSetChange}
                        value={this.state.sets}
                        min="0"
                    />
                    <br />
                    <br />

                    <input className="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Add Workout!" />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect((state) => state)(AddWorkout);
```

that's what I have so far and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I have another form that basically does the same thing and that works perfectly and it written almost exactly the same.

```
import {AddWorkoutSessions} from "../../services/api";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

export class AddWorkoutSession extends Component {
    state = {
        name: "",
    };

    handleNameChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({name: event.target.value});
    };

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        AddWorkoutSessions(this.state, this.props.user.user.id).then((res) =>
            this.props.dispatch({type: "ADD_WORKOUT_SESSION", payload: res})
        );
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Add a New Workout Session!
                <form className="WorkoutSessionsForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>Name: </label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        onChange={this.handleNameChange}
                        value={this.state.name}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Add This Session" />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect((state) => state)(AddWorkoutSession);
```

that is the other form I have and that works perfectly

```
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {deleteWorkout} from "../../services/api";

const WorkoutList = (props) => {
    const state = useSelector((state) => state);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleDelete = (workout) => {
        deleteWorkout(workout.workout_session_id, workout.id).then((data) => data);

        dispatch({type: "DELETE_WORKOUT", payload: workout});
    };

    const renderWorkouts = props.workouts.map((workout) => (
        <li
            onClick={() => console.log(workout)}
            key={workout.id}
            className="workouts"
        >
            {workout.name} with{" "}
            {workout.weight === 0 ? "bodyweight" : `${workout.weight}LB`} for{" "}
            {workout.reps} reps for {workout.sets} sets!{" "}
            <span className="deleteWorkout" onClick={() => handleDelete(workout)}>
                &times;
            </span>
        </li>
    ));

    // const renderWorkoutsTwo = state

    return (
        <div>
            {console.log(state.workout_sessions)}
            {props ? renderWorkouts : null}
        </div>
    );
};

export default WorkoutList;
```

the code above is my "show" page that basically shows all the workouts that are saved in the backend.

i apologize for any confusion. I'm still new to coding and need to be better at explaining myself.

Comment: Can you provide other form for comparison? Or create reproducible example for debug.

Comment: I edited it so it shows the other form/component.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the components `state` object to render the data. So even if you get new redux values from the store, the `state` object will not be updated. To reset the `state` you can use the `componentDidUpdate` method. But it would be much easier to rewrite the class component to a function component und use `useEffect` to do the reset.

Btw: You can also reduce the `handleChange` methods to one by adding the `name` attribute to the input fields according to the property name in the `state` object and refer to it in the method:

```js
    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    };
```

Comment: I kind of understand what you are saying, But how come when I do it for my other component, It updates the data without me having to refresh the page, i edited my original post to show the second component.

BTW, for the first component shown, I have it inside a modal, would that have anything to do with it?

Comment: @JPatino94 Maybe I have misunderstood your question. Do you have the problem, the data is not shown in another component or inside the modal dialog?

Comment: yes i have another component that shows all the data that is saved in the backend. maybe I have been showing the wrong components. I Apologize, I will edit the original post and put in that component as well.